# Restore purchases in In-app Billing (IAB Version 3) android

Tags: java, android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

Google has upgraded to IAB3(In App Billing version 3).
First what a issue in example code.. `super.onDestroy()` is missed.

I implemented v3 with the help of http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html

It is tested on phone, does not work in emulator.It stuck in emulator.

My issue is, I did not see the API for restoring transactions. How can I restore purchases with IAB3? Is it `mService.getPurchases(apiVersion, packageName, type, continuationToken)`. Has anyone tested this?? Does this returns purchased items from locally stored items or does it restore purchased items?
Uninstalling application does not have `continuationToken`. Should it be `null`?

And What about when the purchase state changes??

Please help!

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT :**

Google has updated the In app billing library and solved the `super.onDestroy()` issue.
They have also added some additional features.

Comment: The query purchase that occurs right after set up does this.
I am trying for the same but i have an another issue that is after i got result "ITEM is already owned and again i try to call launchPurchaseFlow. It give up an exception "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't start async operation (launchPurchaseFlow) because another async operation(launchPurchaseFlow) is in progress.
".
I do not know how to go through it.

Comment: For testing, should I publish application or Will do with draft??.. My application is not published on play(not a single version).

Comment: You just require to publish your in-app product not the app.

Answer (score 3):

To make item consumable you have to sent a consume request and you have to do that in separate thread.

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == 1111) {
        int responseCode = data.getIntExtra("RESPONSE_CODE", 0);
        String purchaseData = data.getStringExtra("INAPP_PURCHASE_DATA");
        String dataSignature = data.getStringExtra("INAPP_DATA_SIGNATURE");
        Logger.printMessage(TAG, "on activity result reponse"
                + responseCode, Logger.DEBUG);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && responseCode == 0) {
            try {
                JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(purchaseData);
                String sku = jo.getString("productId");
                String title = jo.getString("title");
                addChipsToBalance(sku);
                final String token = jo.getString("purchaseToken");
                Toast.makeText(BuyChipsActivity.this,
                        "You have bought " + title + ". Enjoy the game!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                new Thread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        Logger.printMessage(TAG, "inside run", Logger.DEBUG);
                        try {
                            int response = mService.consumePurchase(3,
                                    getPackageName(), token);
                            Logger.printMessage(TAG, "inside run response"
                                    + response, Logger.DEBUG);
                        } catch (RemoteException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            Logger.printMessage(TAG, "exception here 1",
                                    Logger.DEBUG);
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }).start();
                // alert("You have bought the " + sku +
                // ". Excellent choice,  adventurer!");
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // alert("Failed to parse purchase data.");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

But sometimes consume request is not completed on google end so you may want to query the purchased item list and consume it with the purchase token. I did like this

```
   private void showPreviousPurchases() {
    Logger.printMessage(TAG, "previous purchases", Logger.DEBUG);
    if (mService == null) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Something Went Wrong. Try later",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    }
    Bundle ownedItems = null;
    ;
    try {
        ownedItems = mService.getPurchases(3, getPackageName(), "inapp",
                null);
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (ownedItems == null) {
        Logger.printMessage(TAG, "criical error ", Logger.DEBUG);
        return;
    }
    int response = ownedItems.getInt("RESPONSE_CODE");
    if (response == 0) {
        ArrayList<String> ownedSkus = ownedItems
                .getStringArrayList("INAPP_PURCHASE_ITEM_LIST");
        ArrayList<String> purchaseDataList = ownedItems
                .getStringArrayList("INAPP_PURCHASE_DATA_LIST");
    /*  ArrayList<String> signatureList = ownedItems
                .getStringArrayList("INAPP_DATA_SIGNATURE");
        String continuationToken = ownedItems
                .getString("INAPP_CONTINUATION_TOKEN");*/

        for (int i = 0; i < purchaseDataList.size(); ++i) {
            String purchaseData = purchaseDataList.get(i);
            Logger.printMessage(TAG, "json  = " + purchaseData,
                    Logger.DEBUG);
            // String signature = signatureList.get(i);
            String sku = ownedSkus.get(i);

            addChipsAndMakeItConsumable(purchaseData);
            // do something with this purchase information
            // e.g. display the updated list of products owned by user
        }

        // if continuationToken != null, call getPurchases again
        // and pass in the token to retrieve more items
    }

}

private void addChipsAndMakeItConsumable(String purchaseData) {

    try {
        JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(purchaseData);
        String sku = jo.getString("productId");
        // String title = jo.getString("title");
        addChipsToBalance(sku);
        final String token = jo.getString("purchaseToken");
        Logger.printMessage(TAG, "id  = " + sku, Logger.DEBUG);

        Logger.printMessage(TAG, "inside run", Logger.DEBUG);
        try {
            int response = mService.consumePurchase(3, getPackageName(),
                    token);
            Logger.printMessage(TAG, "inside run response" + response,
                    Logger.DEBUG);
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Logger.printMessage(TAG, "exception here 1", Logger.DEBUG);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // alert("You have bought the " + sku +
        // ". Excellent choice,  adventurer!");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // alert("Failed to parse purchase data.");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: consume means item will be available to buy again. is it so???... I want to make one time purchase, once user purchase. he/she can use pro feature lifetime. If app will be uninstalled then i want to restore purchases for that particular user. so let me know how can i restore transaction/purchase. If I refund item then how user get notified??

Comment: Hey user1194037,
I tried your function  to get info about latest purchase works very well for the first time but if i tried it again after Uninstalling my app then it does nothing. 
If case is that Google provide us a product id that can be able to purchase once throughout the app else it does not make sense to restore transaction .
Do you have any idea regarding this??
Well i am using "android.test.purchase" as product id.
Please try this after uninstall your app and kindly let me know if it works at your end
thanks..kabir :)

Comment: If the user is running your application for the first time, in that case you can check if there are any preowned in app products, if there are then restore that particular feature.

Comment: okay so **getPurchase** returns purchased items. IWill do for restore transaction.Now If application owner refunds then How user can get notified in IBV3. In old version od Inapp Billing. OnpurchaseStateChanged listener is there. Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

In your IabHelper.java which is an example in your /android-sdk/extras/google/play_billing/samples/  put this code to get all the item that has been purchased by the user. This will return an JSON array of purchased data. You can also used Purchase.java to parse with, which is available also in the samples folder.

```
     public ArrayList<String> getAllPurchases() throws RemoteException{
     Bundle ownedItems = mService.getPurchases(3, mContext.getPackageName(),"inapp", null);

     int response = getResponseCodeFromBundle(ownedItems);
     logDebug("Owned items response: " + String.valueOf(response));
     if (response != BILLING_RESPONSE_RESULT_OK) {
         logDebug("getPurchases() failed: " + getResponseDesc(response));

     }
     if (!ownedItems.containsKey(RESPONSE_INAPP_ITEM_LIST)
             || !ownedItems.containsKey(RESPONSE_INAPP_PURCHASE_DATA_LIST)
             || !ownedItems.containsKey(RESPONSE_INAPP_SIGNATURE_LIST)) {
         logError("Bundle returned from getPurchases() doesn't contain required fields.");
     }

     ArrayList<String> purchaseDataList = ownedItems.getStringArrayList(RESPONSE_INAPP_PURCHASE_DATA_LIST);
     return purchaseDataList;
}
```

And into your Main activity

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity{
  private IabHelper mHelper;
      private String arrayString;
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mHelper = new IabHelper(this,"YOUR PUBLIC KEY" );
      mHelper.enableDebugLogging(true);
      mHelper.startSetup(new IabHelper.OnIabSetupFinishedListener() {

        public void onIabSetupFinished(IabResult result) {

        if (!result.isSuccess()) { // Oh noes, there was a problem.
            Toast.makeText(this,"Problem setting up in-app billing: " + result,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
              return;
          }

        arrayString=mHelper.getAllPurchases().toString();

        Log.d("Purchases: ",""+arrayString);


        array = new JSONArray(arrayString);

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject row = array.getJSONObject(i);    
            productId=row.getString("productId");  //this will get the product id's that has been purchased.

            Log.e("To be restored:", " PRODUCT ID's "+productId);
        }

      });         
    }
}
```

I hope this will help you. ^_^ Thanks.