# Restore Transaction in In-app Billing Version 3 android

Tags: android, in-app-billing

I am using In-app v3 for android every thing working fine except restore transaction.

For example : - i have downloaded app from market and did in-app purchase every thing work here now suppose i have uninstall the app from device and after 2 days again downloaded then again its taking full purchasing.

How can i manage here restore transaction please help me.

Comment: Check this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/13985868/457982