# Android In App Billing Purchased Items List

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

Hi I am developing android app which contains In app billing feature. When I purchase an item from my app, clicking the button and filling the card no, exp date,cvv etc... is working fine. But I want list of purchased items from splash screen itself. Is this possible to get list of purchased items. Please help me to solve this.

And also I saw some thing like calling queryInvertoryListener. But it depends another mService thing and mService in null for me right now.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: check this links: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13890007/restore-purchases-in-in-app-billing-iab-version-3-android and http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html#billing-requests
Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

On the Android developer website is a load of information, you probably know that. I just did a quick google and came across [this](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html) page. Basically if you scroll down a bit it says you can use

```
Bundle ownedItems = mService.getPurchases(3, getPackageName(), "inapp", null);
```

to get purchased items, of course with your app specific variables in that line of code.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I already tried this, as of now I am getting null pointer exception.